# I can't get all the rows from a table selenium, Python

Tags: python, java, selenium, automation

I am trying to get a count of all the rows in the HTML table using Python Selenium. My table contains 184 rows, but my code returns only 33 as Row Count with scrolling. I have checked to inspect the element it is showing only 33 rows, once I scroll down old rows are deleted from inspect element and new rows were added. So, it is maintained at 33 as constant. In this case how can take 184 as Row Count and traverse all the rows

My solution was:

```
i = 0
        l = []
        while True:

            i += 1
            
            xpath_row = '//*[@id="fmEviewTable_tbody"]/tr['+ str(i) +']/td[7]'
            time.sleep(0.5)
            try:
                row_text = WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath_row))).text
            except TimeoutException:
                print("element not found")
            print(f"line {i}, date: {row_text}")
            l.append(row_text)
            
            if i % 10 == 0:
                self.driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
                time.sleep(1)

            
            #stopping the loop at the end of row table

            try:
                self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="fmEviewTable_tbody"]/tr['+ str(i) +']/td[7]')
            except:
                break
```

image bellow it's a print screen

[print screen of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94wbJ.png)

[Inspect element print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7mT0.png)

Comment: Use `move_to_element(to_element)` instead of `send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)`.

Comment: i didn't work i'm still getting the same problem

Comment: you have to get rows during scrolling the page - every row has unique `data-rowid` so you should recognize if you count some row again. But you didn't add url for this page and we can't see page, we can't run you code, and we can't read in your mind - so we can't help you.

Comment: you could use `set()` to keep all `data-rowid` which you find when you scroll. So you can get all `data-rowid`, add to `set()`, next scroll and get again all `data-rowid` and add to the same `set`, and scroll again, etc.

Comment: could you please explain in more detail, and i'm sorry because i didn't put the url because it's not accessible for everyone,

Comment: this is how the url looks like https://10.211.24.5:31943/ossfacewebsite/index.html#Access/fmAlarmLog

Comment: and please could you explain how can i use this data-rowid to access to the content of each row

Answer (score 0):

**1**. Hope you are clear on how to access each row/cell on the table (the visible 33 rows) and extract data from them.

-- lets have two 2d arrays: Main array, last_page array.

0. Capture first page data and append to Main 2d array.
1. Save the current page data to last_page 2d array
2. Navigate to next page (last row cell click and then page down etc.)
3. Capture current page data.
4. Check if it matches with last_page 2d array or not -
   if matches, we are at the last page -- break
5. Otherwise append the page data to Main 2d array
6. Repeat steps from 1.

The final result table will be the Main 2d array after removing the duplicate rows if any.
-- If duplicate rows are possible in the original web table, we will have a challenge in differentiating them with the duplicate entries that came as part of our scraping.

**2**. Another possibility is to ,
Check if the js library used here to create table has any methods exposed to get all the rows data. (eg. eviewtableObj.getData()) .Something you can call using execute_script.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response I tried all of these steps but script stop running in 33 row and gives me TimeoutException

Comment: You don't need to wait for the element to be visible if you are extracting the text from the element -- elements outside the viewport will never be visible. so dont use webdriver wait-- directly go for text.
Also for you to click on that while navigating, either you can use scrollntoView() method in java script and then click(). Otherwise try a java script click directly.

Comment: I changed my code by using scrollintoview but when i get the last row for the first page i doesn't scroll down